# glGetShaderInfoLog with string

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm am doing a shader class which have a method returning shader's logs:

```
std::string Shader::GetShaderInfoLog(){
    GLint TotalLenght=0;
    GetShaderiv(GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&TotalLenght);
    std::string logs;
    logs.reserve(TotalLenght);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(name, TotalLenght, NULL, &logs[0] );
    return logs;
}
```

For strange reason, logs string is empty even with a shader which have compilation error.
I have tried with a char array :

```
std::string Shader::GetShaderInfoLog(){
    GLint TotalLenght=0;
    GetShaderiv(GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&TotalLenght); 
    char logs[TotalLenght];
    glGetShaderInfoLog(name, TotalLenght, NULL, logs);
    return std::string(logs);
}
```

And this one work well. So my question is why it don't work with a string ?

Comment: FYI variable-length arrays (`char logs[TotalLenght]`)  are not part of the c++ standard (it's only an extension that a compiler might support), so that is also wrong.

Comment: @t.niese good to know, that's why I will use string instead of char arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve) just increases the capacity of the string. But does not change it's size.

You need to [`resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) it:

```
std::string Shader::GetShaderInfoLog(){
    GLint TotalLenght=0;
    GetShaderiv(GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&TotalLenght);
    std::string logs;
    logs.resize(TotalLenght);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(name, TotalLenght, NULL, &logs[0] );
    return logs;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, it work, the book I use to learn openGL use reserve() as a bad way. Thanks

Comment: @Xemuth ok that's strange, maybe they use the string later only with `c_str` or with `&logs[0]` and they didn't recognize the error due to that.

Comment: they only use c_str() but the fonction glGetShaderInfoLog only work with non const char * so it is also an error from them